# Will Ubuntu work on a GPT-partitioned 3TB disk?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I'm new to Ubuntu and I wanted to give it a shot.

I plan on splitting the 3TB I have but it'll have to be GPT format.
Am planning to set up multi OS, Windows 7 is one of them.
I heard that not all versions support this format?

Any advice/suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Also you can refer [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/84544/63025), it will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about Windows, this is probably the wrong place, but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#OS_support_of_GPT you will need Windows 7 64-bit on a computer with EFI for it to work. Ubuntu should work fine with it in either case.