# How can I create a 4TB partition on my software RAID5 device?

Tags: partitioning, raid, gparted, disk-utility, raid5

I have set up a RAID5 device with three 2TB hard drives using `mdadm`. The device was successfully created, but I cannot seem to create a partition on the device.

When I try to make an ext3 or ext4 partition via Disk Utility, I get the following error

```
Error creating partition: helper exited with exit code 1: In part_add_partition: device_file=/dev/md0, start=0, size=4000526106624, type=
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=4000526106624)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
found partition type 0xee => protective MBR for GPT
Exiting MS-DOS parser
Entering EFI GPT parser
GPT magic found
partition_entry_lba=2
num_entries=128
size_of_entry=128
Leaving EFI GPT parser
EFI GPT partition table detected
containing partition table scheme = 3
got it
got disk
new partition
guid '' is not valid
type '' for GPT appear to be malformed
```

I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/84538/17739), but that seems to suggest using `gparted` to do the partitioning. I'm fine with doing that, but my RAID device doesn't show up in the list of `gparted` devices. I suspect because this is a RAID and not a regular disk.

I have already created a GPT partition table on the device. How can I add a partition to my device?

Comment: Check gparted again; it does show raid devices.

Comment: @psusi [Here's what I see in Gparted.](http://i.imgur.com/LHAN8.png). You can see the device in Disk Utility on the bottom listed as `/dev/md0`. I don't see it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fault. I didn't realize I couldn't create a partition while the array was rebuilding.

I thought I had done this in the past, but I guess I waited first.

Once I waited for the rebuild to finish, I was able to successfully create a partition.