# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows on 3TB HDD "exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum"

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have a 3TB hard drive, but when I installed Windows 7 it only allowed me to use 2.2TB.

I want to install Ubuntu in my free hard drive space (which isn't formatted). I supposed I should use the **Something else** option, but I really don't know what to do. I tried the **Install alongside Windows** option and it gave me an error message

> starting sector number, 4294967296 exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

What should I do?

- motherboard : Asus Maximus IV //
- Hard drive    : Western Digital Caviar Green 3TB

Comment: You've hit the maximum size for a msdos partition table. See [trouble creating 3TB partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84538/trouble-creating-3tb-ext4-partition-due-to-msdos-partition-table-imposed-error)

Answer (score 0):

Select "something else" and it will take you to a partition manager screen on the installation, from there you can select where to go with your partitions. Select the hard drive space with the "free space" label and select the "add" button under the chart. Select the radio button "primary" as the type and then type in the size you want Ubuntu to be in the "new partition size" text field, make sure "beginning" is checked underneath this. You will see options like "mount point", you'll want to select that drop down tab and choose "/". You'll also see filesystem types such as EXT3 and EXT4. Select ext3 or ext4, as I've never really noticed a performance drop and select how much space you wish to take up.

It's best to leave some space spare, I use 2gb, to create ANOTHER partition next to the same drive and go through the same procedure only instead of selected filesystem type as something like ext4, select it as "swap space".

If all the settings are entered follow through to the next screen and resume the setup as usual.

Comment: thanks for you answer cossacksman, but i keep getting this error message (starting sector number, 4294967296 exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295)

Comment: How much spare space are we looking at here? Have you tried installing Ubuntu using a space of less than 2TB? partition tables sometimes have trouble with this, try reducing your partition dramatically in a few chunks (say, 200-500GB/time) and see if it works out for you.

Comment: What i was trying was a 750GB partition, but i also tried to partition 2gb and didnt work either

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error while installing debian so I think, this could also work with ubuntu because it is based on debian. To solve this problem I tried reducing the size of my last listed partition on this drive just a little (only 1.3MB or so) and it worked just fine then.

Hopefully this helps somebody with the same problem.