# Can't install linux

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu here but it doesn't works because my HD is a 3TB one , I tried with a 750MB and others ubuntu patchs but it didn't worked...

Please help

Comment: I do not think there is a hard drive limit on the Ubuntu install which can be reached by current HD's. Maybe you can post a bit more detail on what kind of error you are experiencing?

Comment: When i'm selecting "install" an error page appears and tell me :"Starting sector number 4294967296 eceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295."

Answer (score 0):

The limitation you experience is not an Ubuntu limitation but an limitation of the old dos partitioning. see:
[Trouble creating 3TB ext4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84538/trouble-creating-3tb-ext4-partition-due-to-msdos-partition-table-imposed-error)

If you go for a fresh install with a new disk you should select a GUID Partition Table (GPT).

**Warning!!: This Will Delete all data on the disk!!**

Comment: Should I install ubuntu on another disk then ? 
Having 2 OS on different disks seems a bad idea I guess

What if I don't want to delete data ? ^^'

Comment: You simply cannot use a disk above 2TB with MBR partitioning. Not in Windows and not in Ubuntu. If you want to use more then 2TB you have to change the partitioning system to GPT and this cannot be done without loosing the data. So yes, you need a different disk or reinstall all.