# gparted - Disk size smaller after creating partition table + old data gone

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I had the same issue as the guy posting on [Trouble creating 3TB ext4 partition due to msdos-partition-table-imposed error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84538/trouble-creating-3tb-ext4-partition-due-to-msdos-partition-table-imposed-error)

The new 6TB drive I got was only issues 2TB by Microsoft so I booted into gparted "Device->Create Partition Table and select "gpt" from the list." I then booted back up into Windows and G: drive was no longer mounted. I deleted disk0 and recreated it inside Windows disk management however as you can see in the screenshot below the disk size is only 5589GB. Should it be more?

I did use about 300GB of data before doing this and I would like to recover that data but both Windows and gparted can't detect anything more than the 5589GB.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the `1000` vs. `1024` bytes problem.

You see, assuming `1024`, a 6TB drive can hold `6.6E12` bytes. However, assuming `1000`, it can hold `6E12` bytes.

The difference between the two is `6E11` bytes, or `559GB`. Thus, your reported capacity is `559GB` less than what you think it should be.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. So the initial data I installed is gone? I am using full capacity of the drive at it's current state?

Comment: @Toodarday your data is not *gone*, although it may be very difficult to recover depending on how much disk I/O has been done since you re-formatted. For the future, please **always** make backups, *especially* if you're doing anything potentially dangerous like messing with partitions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. It was not important data, luckily.

Comment: @Toodarday that's good :) also, see [here](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/should-i-teach-that-1-kb-1024-bytes-or-1000-bytes) for more reading on `1000` vs `1024`.